# Jquery Dialog is throwing error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am getting this error while I am using 
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method.
I am using Jquery Dialog.

Thanks in advance
Javascript

```
 function showQnsLogic(hdfLogicID) {   
        var qnsString = document.getElementById(hdfLogicID).innerHTML;
        var distance = 10;
        var time = 250;
        var hideDelay = 500;
        var hideDelayTimer = null;
        var beingShown = false;
        var shown = false;
        var info = $('#divqnsLogic');
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
        var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
        $("#divqnsLogic").dialog();
        $('#divqnsLogic').html(qnsString);

    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
     <div id="divqnsProp" class="popupNew">
    <table width="100%;" id="tblContent">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divProperties" style="font: Arial; font-size: 11px; overflow: auto">
                    <div class="descriptionPanelHeader">
                        Question Properties  </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show some **relevant** code?

Comment: Why 3 minus ? :( Is my question is not up to the standard ?

Comment: I think you got the down votes earlier, because you didn't include any code and your question was very vague.

Comment: In the future, when you're asking questions, provide **relevant code**, any **error messages**, and efforts to find the answer. Also, upvote useful answers, and accept an answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: where do you create #divqnsLogic ? and why do you save it in the `info` var but then fetching it again with jquery instead of using `info`?

Answer (score 0):

This error happen sometimes if you don't have the jquery dialog library well included.

And could you give us more details on the error.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error "**Object doesn't support this property or method**" indicates that the `dialog()` method of `$("#divqnsLogic")` could NOT be found.

Since this method is included in JQuery UI, rather than JQuery core, at a guess you've only included the core libraries and need to add a reference to JQuery UI.

e.g. If you [reference](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js) does it solve the problem?